# Xamarin.iOS info,plist not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm running the latest version of everything. When I set the orientation and save and close, my changes are reverted when reopened. Also When I set source for app icons to none, it keeps the old ones and I can't update this. I've deleted bin obj.

Comment: Try to right click info.plist ,exclude from project, and add it again.

Answer (score 0):

Please, Right-click on Info.plist file and choose Properties

Check "Copy to Output Directory" property and set on "Copy always"

Answer (score 0):

The IDE oriOS manifest editor might have some bugs/defects as of VS 2017 v15.8.1. Rather than using the manifest editor, right click on info.plist and "Open With" an XML Editor. You may find 2 keys for Orientation, then remove those values you don't want. In my case, I want Portrait only in both iPhone and iPad. So I have:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```